# Sphinx does not recognize ≤, ≥?

Tags: python-sphinx

Using ≤ and ≥ in csv file will be shown as question marks in html. I have to use <= and >= instead. Is there a better workaround for this?

Comment: Can you show us a sample CSV file and how you use it with Sphinx?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  To expand on @mzjn's comment above, it'd help people to understand your problem if you could edit your question to add a minimal reproducible example (see stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with creating one).